# DataTypeConverter#parseBoolean inconsistent and not honoring its contract

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

The documentation [DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) says its supposed to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if string parameter does not conform to the [lexical value space defined in XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes for xsd:boolean](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean).

The following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String[] testValues = new String[]{null, "", "   ", " true ", " false "
                                       , "  0 ",  "  1 ", "boo", "True"};

    for (String testValue : testValues)
        System.out.printf("test value: %-20s ---result--->  %s\n"
                          , String.format("[%s]", testValue)
                          , result(testValue));

}

private static String result(String x) {
    try {
        return Boolean.valueOf(DatatypeConverter.parseBoolean(x)).toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return String.format("[%s|%s]"
                             , e.getClass().getName()
                             , e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

... produces the output:

```
 [java] test value: [null]               ---result--->  [java.lang.NullPointerException|null]
 [java] test value: []                   ---result--->  [java.lang.NullPointerException|null]
 [java] test value: [   ]                ---result--->  false
 [java] test value: [ true ]             ---result--->  true
 [java] test value: [ false ]            ---result--->  false
 [java] test value: [  0 ]               ---result--->  false
 [java] test value: [  1 ]               ---result--->  true
 [java] test value: [boo]                ---result--->  [java.lang.NullPointerException|null]
 [java] test value: [True]               ---result--->  [java.lang.NullPointerException|null]
```

I have two issues with the output. First is that NPE instead of `IllegalArgumentException` exceptions are thrown. Second and most important is the inconsistent behavior in the handling of the zero length String (throws NPE) versus a whitespace only string (evaluates to `false`) given that the method trims whitespace. Am I missing anything or is there some reasoning behind this behavior?

Comment: It certainly is not correct behavior and should be submitted as a bug.  Possibly related is [this existing Java bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-608) (now closed).  In Java 8, all of those test strings parse as `false` except "true" and "1", and none of them generate any kind of exception.  Still not in accordance with the contract or the XSD spec, but it's a bit closer.